# Setting the data attribute of Handlebars objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I use NodeJs with Express and Handlebars.

I create a grid on the server and send the object to the client. The list contains cells having two properties, x position and y positon.

So I go for this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cells = $(".cell"); // get all cells
  
  $(cells).each(function(i, cell) {
    var currentCell = $(cell);
    var x = currentCell.data("xPos"); // get the xPos
    var y = currentCell.data("yPos"); // get the yPos
    
    currentCell.click(function() { // add a click event to each cell
      console.log(x + " | " + y);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

{{#each map}}
<div class="row">
  {{#each this}}

  <!-- <p>{{this.x}}</p> prints out a correct value! -->
  <!-- <p>{{this.y}}</p> prints out a correct value! -->

  <div class="cell" data-xPos={{this.x}} data-yPos={{this.y}}></div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

When clicking on a cell the console logs

> undefined | undefined

how can I set the data attribute? I just want to pass the information to the client script so I went for the data attribute.

An example DOM after building the page

[image: DOM]

Answer (score 1):

The data attribute has to be

> data-xpos={{this.x}} data-ypos={{this.y}}

So the full HTML would be

```
<div class="cell" data-xpos={{this.x}} data-ypos={{this.y}}></div>
```

and the JS

```
var x = currentCell.data("xpos");
var y = currentCell.data("ypos");
```